# Три вопроса про emacs. - Быстрый scroll, обратный tab и copy/past

Tags: emacs

Уже, наверно, больше 1 месяца на emacs - в принципе, всё нравится. Но. 
До этого пользовалась Sublime, Atom - очень не хватает их быстрого скроллинга. Как быстро попасть, допустим, в середину файла? Можно, конечно, воспользоваться M-g g - jump to line -  но всё равно не особо удобно.

Второй вопрос: в том же Sublime можно было выделить область нужную, нажать на Ctrl + Shift + Tab и вся выделенная область переместиться к левому краю - как такое сделать в emacs?

Третий вопрос: у меня на сочетание клавиш copy стоит команда - 'kill-ring-save, а на past - 'clipboard-yank . Так-то это, вроде, работает, но как только копирую текст с какого-то другого места, потом удаляю у себя в emacs текст и хочу на месте освободившегося места вставить скопированный текст, так у меня вставляется только что удаленный текст! Как это можно решить?

Всем спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Первый вопрос -- если в окне есть слайдер, а у меня он почему-то (по умолчанию?) есть -- как-то не актуален. / Второй -- если честно не понял (может Вы имеете в виду  команду `delete-rectangle`?)  / Третий -- вставка из ring-a -- последнее удаленной/копированное это C-Y, а ппотом предыдущие (назад по кругу) -- M-Y / Т.е. если скопировали что-то (напримерр  в окне браузера) а перед вставкой (`clipboard-yank`) удалили регион в буфере, то нажимаете C-Y (вернется удаление) M-Y (вместо возвращенного  удаления) вставится копипаста.

Comment: Первый вопрос - у меня почему-то такого нет. Но скрол можно оказывается делать M-v - вверх и C-v - вниз.

Comment: Второй - да delete-rectangle, indent-rigidly-right-to-tab-stop - такого рода команды как раз то что надо. 

Третий - да, просто команда yank не помогает clipboard-yank - то что надо.

Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Будет полезно выделить каждый вопрос в отдельное сообщение. В одном вопросе должна быть описана только одна проблема.

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 2):

Желательно, пройти вводный курс, идет вместе с Emacs:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/

```
C-h t
```

**Быстрое перемещение**

Начало буфера:

```
beginning-of-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in‘simple.el’.

It is bound to <begin>, <C-home>, M-<, <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <beg-of-buf>.

(beginning-of-buffer &optional ARG)
```

Конец буфера:

```
end-of-buffer is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘simple.el’.

It is bound to <C-end>, M->, <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <end-of-buf>.

(end-of-buffer &optional ARG)
```

Верх-центр-низ видимой зоны:

```
C-l runs the command recenter-top-bottom (found in global-map),
which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘window.el’.

It is bound to C-l.

(recenter-top-bottom &optional ARG)
```

Использовать imenu:

```
imenu is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in ‘imenu.el’.

(imenu INDEX-ITEM)

Jump to a place in the buffer chosen using abuffer menu or mouse menu.
INDEX-ITEM specifies the position.
See ‘imenu-choose-buffer-index’for more information.
```

Перейти к определению функции-переменной-классу:

```
M-. runs the command xref-find-definitions (found in global-map),
which is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in ‘xref.el’.

It is bound to M-., <menu-bar> <edit> <goto> <xref-find-def>.

(xref-find-definitions IDENTIFIER)
```

**Выравнивание**

```
M-j l
   Make the region left-filled (set-justification-left).
M-j r
   Make the region right-filled (set-justification-right).
M-j f
   Make the region fully-justified (set-justification-full).
M-j c
M-S
   Make the region centered (set-justification-center).
M-j u
   Make the region unfilled (set-justification-none).
```

**Буфер обмена (kill-ring)**

```
C-y
    Yank the last kill into the buffer, at point (yank).
M-y
    Replace the text just yanked with an earlier
    batch of killed text (yank-pop). See Earlier Kills.
C-M-w
    Cause the following command, if it is a kill command,
    to append to the previous kill (append-next-kill).
```

Посмотрите cua-mode:

```
cua-mode is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in ‘cua-base.el’.

It is bound to <menu-bar> <options> <cua-emulation-mode>, <menu-bar> <options>
<cua-mode>.

(cua-mode &optional ARG)

Toggle Common User Access style editing (CUA mode).
With a prefix argument ARG, enable CUA mode if ARG is positive,
and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable the mode
if ARG is omitted or nil.
```